# javascript - problems with filter, RegExp and variables

Tags: javascript

is there an easier way to test the character, i saw something about RegExp the other day but it's applied diffently then what im doing now. the piont is example:

> if firstname only contains `a to z` then it *return true* if give count a +1 and later one when count is 8 or greater it will submit post.

But it's not working when i putin number in firstname.

do some of u find a error im the script or something i could have done better?

many thanks.

```js
var count = 0;

function checkEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('Email'); // haalt record op en slaat op als variable
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})/; // hier wordt gecheckt of de records correct zijn ingevuld

    // hier staat als de test terug komt moet dingen die niet in de filter staat dan voer iets geldig in
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    alert('Voer geldig email adres in.');
    email.focus;// hier wordt gelet als de muis of met die toetsenbord weg gaat van veld

            return false;
    

 }
 else {
     count = count+1;
 }
    
}

function checkVoornaam() {

    var voornaam = document.getElementById('voornaam');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z])/;

    if (!filter.test(voornaam.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw voornaam in.');
    voornaam.focus;
    return false;
 }
 else {
     count = count+1;
 }
}

function checkachternaam() {

    var achternaam = document.getElementById('achternaam');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z])/;

    if (!filter.test(achternaam.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw achternaam in.');
    achternaam.focus;
    return false;
}
else {
    count = count+1;
}
}



function checkStraat() {

    var straat = document.getElementById('Straatnaam');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+)/;

    if (!filter.test(straat.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw straatnaam in.');
    straat.focus;
    return false;
 }
 else {
     count = count+1;
 }
}

function checkSn() {

    var sn = document.getElementById('Huisnummer');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9,#.-]+)/;

    if (!filter.test(sn.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw huisnummer in.');
    sn.focus;
    return false;
}
else {
    count = count+1;
}
}

function checkPS() {

    var ps = document.getElementById('Postcode');
    var filter = /^([1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2})/;

    if (!filter.test(ps.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw postcode in.');
    ps.focus;
    return false;
 }
 else {
     count = count+1;
 }
}

function checkWP() {

    var WP = document.getElementById('Woonplaats');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z\-']+)/;

    if (!filter.test(WP.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw woonplaats in.');
    WP.focus;
    return false;
}
else {
    count = count+1;
}
}

function checkTel() {

    var tel = document.getElementById('Telefoonnummer');
    var filter = /^(\d{3}\d{3}\d{4})/;

    if (!filter.test(tel.value)) {
    alert('Voer uw telefoonnummer in.');
    tel.focus;
    return false;
}
else {
    count = count+1;
}
}



// global var
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('Wachtwoord');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('Herhaal_Wachtwoord');   



// functie checkt terplekke of ww1 en ww2 overeenkomen
function checkPass()
{
    //Store the Confimation Message Object ...
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    //Set the colors we will be using ...
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
    //Compare the values in the password field 
    //and the confirmation field
    if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
        //The passwords match. 
        //Set the color to the good color and inform
        //the user that they have entered the correct password 
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!";
//        registreren.register show();
    }else{
        //The passwords do not match.
        //Set the color to the bad color and
        //notify the user.
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!";
   //     registreren.register hide();
    }
} 


function validateForm() {
   
    
var fields = ["voornaam", "achternaam", "Email", "Wachtwoord", "Herhaal_Wachtwoord", "Straatnaam", "Huisnummer", "Postcode","Woonplaats","Telefoonummer"];
      
if  (pass1.value !== pass2.value){
        alert ("Wachtwoord komen niet overeen");
        return false;
       }
                               if (count < 8 ){  
                        alert("iets is niet goed ingevuld");
                        return false;
                        }
            var l = fields.length;
            var fieldname;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                fieldname = fields[i];
                    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
                    alert(fieldname + " mag niet leeg zijn");
                    return false;
                    }
                }
                     //   if (count < 8 ){  
                      //  alert("iets is niet goed ingevuld");
                       // return false;
                      //  }
               
                  
                    
              
            }
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle or plunker. A working code helps is resolving the issue

Comment: Your description is little unclear. Can you explain properly what you are trying to achieve? Probably give some examples with output.

Comment: Where do you declare `count`, where do you check its value, where do you call these functions, and where do you submit the form?

Comment: i have updated the script with to whole page count is declared above the page globally and submitting under the page

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/^([a-zA-Z])/` only matches if the string starts with a-z, try this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

And:

```
function valid_firstname(firstName) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(firstName);
}

valid_firstname('John'); // true
valid_firstname('John42'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function checkVoornaam the regex:

> var filter = /^([a-zA-Z])/;

Miss the *$* char at the end.

Now it will match Mario and also Mario1 and also Mario2Ciao and so on.

It should be:

```
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z])$/;
```